# Probability that player wins

Tags: probability

In a game a coin is tossed (2n+m) times and a player wins if he does not get any two consecutive outcomes same for at least 2n times in a row. How to calculate probability that player wins game.

I can understand the outcomes will be (HTHTHTHTHTHTH...) OR (THTHTHTHTHTHTHTH...) atleast 2n times but how to relate it to get probability ?

Comment: Not sure I understand the rules.  Do you mean that there are at least $2n$ throws which do not match their predecessor?  Does the first throw count?  Let's do $n=1,m=1$ explicitly.  Then the possible outcomes are $HHH,HHT,HTH,THH,HTT,THT,TTH,TTT$.  Which of these are winners?

Comment: Supposing that, for the $n=1,m=1$ case, you say that only $THT$ and $HTH$ are winners then:  Except for the first throw, every toss has a well defined predecessor.  The probability that this toss doesn't match the predecessor is $\frac 12$.  Thus you have $2n+m-1$ independent Bernoulli trials and you demand at least $2n$ wins.  Easy computation.

Answer (score 0):

$2^{2n+m}$ outcomes in total.

desired ways are $\dbinom{2n+m}{2n}\times 2$

so, probability is

$\dfrac{\dbinom{2n+m}{2n}\times 2}{2^{2n+m}}$

Comment: didnt get how you got desired ways..its atleast 2n not exaxctly 2n ??